# Lost files on ext3 external drive

Tags: windows-7, ext3

I have a 500Gb portable HDD that I formatted with ext3 to use with an NAS. Yesterday I was reorganizing the thing and dragged a folder with all my old photos, a few videos, old documents, etc. to a new folder I had created. Once it started moving the files it said there was over an hour remaining to move all the files, so I clicked the Cancel button. After I did that, the folder I was moving just disappeared.

I found a program called DiskInternals Linux Recovery that is supposed to be able to recover the info, but it won't work over my network. It just sees the HDD partitions on my PC. The only advice I have seen was to connect the external HDD directly to my PC, but in my experience if I do that my WIndows machine will start to reformat the drive as soon as I connect it. Is it safe to connect that drive to my Windows 7 machine? Is the DiskInternals program the best way to go, or should I try something else?

Answer (score 0):

A method I use often is to install a Linux based System Rescue CD onto a USB thumb drive. Then you can boot into it, hook up your NAS drive directly to your PC and use the System Rescue CD to do what you need. You can even install the Linux recovery tool you found onto your System Rescue.

Here is a link to a solid System Rescue CD: http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage

Comment: any luck with this?